# Csvhelper not parsing correctly to list

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to read the provided CSV text into a List with CSVHelper, but it skips some records.

I made the records in the image below red so to make my problem more clear, it only adds those red fields (52 in total) to the list but not the comma seperated text after it, for instance: 488273,1482,14526113. It adds the first but skips the 1482 and 14526113. I need to have those added too.

**Code**

```
csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
csv.Configuration.TrimFields = false;

List<int> playerInfo = csv.GetRecords<int>().ToList();
```

**Image**

the red markings are not only those but to give an examle, it's about all the first records.
[image: CSV]

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;

namespace stack1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //list of int
            var result = new List<int>();
            //total 
            int sum=0;
            int recordValue;
            using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(@"C:\sample.csv"))
            {
                var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader);
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                csv.Configuration.TrimFields = false;

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    for (var i = 0; csv.TryGetField(i, out recordValue); i++)
                    {
                        result.Add(recordValue);
                        sum += recordValue;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the solution for me

Comment: what exactly you want from that csv file?

Comment: It doesn't get the last two records after the comma (,). Example: 487207,1484,15047920. From those it only adds the 487207 to the list. But i also need 1484 and 15047920 added to the list. The getRecords doesn't do that correctly.

Comment: I have verified with above sample code. Can you please check your CSV file format. Also let me what is the output if you are using my code.

Comment: the result is that it only returns the first two. Example line: 468709,1526,16860019 636178,70,743222 386482,80,2072114 now it only returns the 468709 and 1526 as seperate List<int> items. Is my csv format incorrect maybe?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `csv.GetRecords<T>()` CSVHelper maps *the entirety of* each row (line) to the type specified. You are mapping to the type `int`. You have 3 values in each row of your CSV. These 3 values cannot be mapped to a single `int`. CSVHelper simply maps the first record in each line.

If you want to use the CsvReader, you should define a custom class (with 3 int properties) and use `csv.GetRecords<MyCustomCsvClass>()`. You may also want/need to create a custom CsvClassMap. The CSVHelper documentation is excellent: [Mapping By Index](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping-index).

Alternatively, you could use the [CsvParser class](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#reading-parsing) which does no mapping or type conversion. It simply returns a `string[]` for each row.